# Pyspark usage of ArrayWritable

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I try to save a key-value RDD on pyspark.  Each cell of the RDD has the type, written in pseudo-code of :

```
((str,str),(int,[(int,int),...]))`
```

I want to save it on hadoop filesystems.  For that effect, I convert the list into a tuple and call `.saveAsSequenceFile`.  However reloading the rdd with `sc.sequenceFile` fails with `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable.<init>()`.

Here is a minimal example that tries to save a RDD of `(int,int)`.

```
import pyspark as spark, math

scConf = spark.SparkConf().setAppName('minimal_example')
sc = spark.SparkContext( conf = scConf )

def divs( x ):
    for n in xrange(1, int(math.sqrt(x))+1 ):
        if x % n == 0: yield n
def constructor( i ):
    return ( i, tuple(divs(i)) )

rdd = sc.parallelize(map(constructor,range(2,61)))
rdd.saveAsSequenceFile("min.seq")
```

When I load it with the interactive `pyspark` using sc.sequenceFile, it fails as well.  What's wrong?  Why does it, in python, tries to save arrays while I actually have tuple.  And also how to extend ArrayWritable in pyspark to have a default constructor?

Comment: Could you post sc.parallelize(map(constructor,range(2,61))).take(2) ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need sequence files ? You can saveAsTextFile, load text file and map to recover values.

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile('test') 

sc.textFile('test').map(lambda row: ast.literal_eval(row))
```